# How to open and split the most recent image from isolated storage (WP8)?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I am currently developing an app that would do the following tasks:

1- taking a picture and saving it in both : Isolated storage and the photo gallery.

2-then loading the picture in a different page while being split into different sections.

so I followed this tutorial on how to capture a photo and save it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202956(v=vs.105).aspx

now I am stuck on the part of viewing and splitting the most recent image in a different page.

Any solutions or ideas?

Comment: Clarify what you mean by different pages/different sections.  Do you just want to load a list of images onto a single screen, then have them tap the image and load the full resolution image onto a separate page?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear about that, all I want is a way to view the most recent photo captured by my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sorry for not being clear about that, all I want is a way to view the most recent photo captured by my app

The sample Camera app saves the photo to the camera roll as well as the application isolated storage.  Here's the code snippet they used.

```
// Save photo as JPEG to the local folder.
using (IsolatedStorageFile isStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream targetStream = isStore.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        // Initialize the buffer for 4KB disk pages.
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;

        // Copy the image to the local folder. 
        while ((bytesRead = e.ImageStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            targetStream.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
}
```

---

As you can see they save it with the file name `fileName`, so all you have to do is keep a `List<string>` of all the `fileName` that you used.  Each time you save a new image, you want to add that `fileName` to the List.

You can saved the list by using ApplicationSettings

```
if (!IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("recent_images"))
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("recent_images", YOUR_LIST);        
}
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
```

That way next time you load the app you can get the List again (so basically you tombstoned the List)

```
List<string> recent_images = (List<string>) IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["recent_images"];
```

---

Now to load your recent images

```
<!-- create the container in xaml -->
<Image x:Name="myImage"></Image>


// this function loads an image from isolated storage and returns a bitmap
private static BitmapImage GetImageFromIsolatedStorage(string imageName)
{
    var bimg = new BitmapImage();
    using (var iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (var stream = iso.OpenFile(imageName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            bimg.SetSource(stream);
        }
    }
    return bimg;
}


// load the first image in recent images
BitmapImage first = GetImageFromIsolatedStorage(recent_images[0]);

// set the BitmapImage as the source of myImage to display it on the screen
this.myImage.Source = first;
```

---

Just read the their code and my code line by line.  It's not too hard if you don't skip steps.

Comment: I got this error: BitmapImage first = GetImageFromIsolatedStorage(recent_images[0];                          An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @AnasWaleed break points are your friends -- use them.  First, verify that you're actually saving the image, does the MSDN camera app run and save it to isolated storage?  Basically put a break point in that while loop @ `targetStream.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);`  does your break point hit?

Comment: @AnasWaleed If yes, then the next to do is just load back the same file that you saved, with `BitmapImage first = GetImageFromIsolatedStorage("1.jpg");`, does that work?

Comment: @AnasWaleed If yes, then you're incorrectly saving your `List<string>` or you forgot to `List<string> recent_images = new List<string>();` or you didn't add anything to the List resulting in the 0 index being null

Comment: When I change it to 1.jpg I get the following error in this line:  var bimg = new BitmapImage();An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll

Additional information: Invalid cross-thread access.